# How to come out of screen session on a remote server?

Tags: macos, unix, ssh, command-line

I am not able to recall I used to do it in past. I am connecting to a remote linux machine from my MacOS. I could create the session by running `screen S sessionname` but unable to come out of it without exiting. I tried `Command+D` but not working neither `control+D`.

Comment: Did you look at `man screen` to see how to send commands to `screen`?

Comment: The default key combo to detach a `screen` session Control-A D (that is, press Control-A, release the keys, then D). That will let you go back to the terminal but leave the `screen` session running so that can reattach at a later time with `screen -r`.